# A login form will not display in my WebView

Tags: android

I have a `WebView` loading the URL https://pro.mywellness.com. This works fine, but when navigating to the login page, the login form does not appear - https://pro.mywellness.com/Login It is pretty much just a blank page except for the header and footer.

I have enabled internet in the manifest and enabled javascript in the activity. I've no idea what is causing the form to not display as it works fine in a normal browser. Any help that anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.webkit.WebSettings;

import android.webkit.WebView;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    //Obtain the WebSettings object//
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    //Call setJavaScriptEnabled(true)//
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://pro.mywellness.com");
    // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebView());
}

@Override

public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return;
    }
    // Otherwise defer to system default behavior.
    super.onBackPressed();
}

}
```

The MyWebView() method :

```
import android.net.Uri;

import android.webkit.WebView;

import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MyWebView extends WebViewClient {

@Override

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    return !Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("pro.mywellness.com");

}

}
```

Comment: MyWebView() what does this method do?

Comment: It is used to block access to over domains. I have tested removing this and it does nothing - I'll add the code to my question.

Comment: It also prevents links from opening in the devices browser.

Comment: [INFO:CONSOLE(281)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: https://pro.mywellness.com/Scripts/Login/login.js?v=201807260742270000 (281) --->i run your code i got this errro in log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this line in your code before loadurl :-

```
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("https://pro.mywellness.com/Login");
```

It will work. :)

Comment: Ha it did as well! Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't suppose you could explain what that line of code does please?

Comment: it is basically use for security and space saving, and by default it is disable for website, so that is why we need to enable it :)

Comment: You can accept the answer, if it worked for you @Stephen :)